# WPF : Reorder WrapPanel content via drag and drop?

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, wrappanel

I am looking for a way to reorder the content (items) of a WPF WrapPanel via drag and drop. I just want to click on an item and drag it to a new position.

To my understanding this is a very common task and I wonder I someone already did this or has any idea how to implement this functionality.

I did a google search already but found nothing. Maybe it is more difficult than I expected.

Comment: I'm looking for this also: something exactly like the taskbar in Win7

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've written a library which may help: default behaviour is to allow re-ordering within the same control:

http://code.google.com/p/gong-wpf-dragdrop/

Ah I notice you're talking about just a WrapPanel: you'll need to use an ItemsControl with a WrapPanel:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapPanel />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works like a dream.

Comment: Hi, any ideas how to do this programatically?

Comment: Btw, great DnD API (gong-wpf-dragdrop), I just added it to the OWASP O2 Platform

Answer (score 4):

A wrap panel won't give you the functionality you are looking for since it is just for layout. Instead look at adding the drag and drop functionality to a ListBox and change the ItemsPanelTemplate of that ListBox to use a wrap panel.

---

- [Changing a list box to use a Wrap Panel](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/CustomListBoxLayoutInWPF.aspx)
- [Library for Drag and drop (from Groky's answer)](http://code.google.com/p/gong-wpf-dragdrop/)